# Search user's all fileds in drupal 7

Tags: 7, users, search

I want to make a text fields that will make user able to search all the fields. I have tried few modules but nothing is working for me the way i want.

Comment: This is a rather broad question. It would helpful you say which modules you have already tried, to avoid somebody suggests one of those modules.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have tried view filter populate and better exposed filter.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what issues you ran into with view filter populate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple field values into one (hidden) field using [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field). Be sure to save the value to the database, so that it can be used as a Views exposed filter. You'll also need to re-save each existing node in order to populate the computed field ([VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) can do that in bulk).

This is another interesting idea (I haven't tried it): http://drupal.org/node/732458#comment-4750574